# print every member's name of the struct

Tags: c

Suppose I have a `struct`, it's defined like this:

```
struct node {
  int a;
  char b;
};
```

How can I find and print every struct members name using pointers or something? (Example output here: `a` and `b`.

Comment: What "every element"? There are just two *members* in the structure? Do you have an array or a pointer to some allocated memory? What have you tried yourself? What does your code look like? What's wrong with your code?

Comment: 1. What is some methods you tried yourself?
2. What exactly do you want?
3. What do you mean by "every elements"?

Comment: @Magisch Thanks for your reply. I just want to print out every member's name.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks for your time. I mean I know there is a struct, but I don't know what it looks like. I want to print out every member's name.

Comment: @HuangJie So what you really want is find out how many members there are, and print out what they are and their names?

Comment: C doesn't have [introspection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection) so it's not possible (if I understand your question correctly).

Comment: @Magisch Yes, that's what I'm thinking.

Comment: @HuangJie refer to my Answer or better yet Alter Mann's Answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Member names are unknown at runtime, so you can not (unless you manually specify them).

[X Macros](http://www.drdobbs.com/the-new-c-x-macros/184401387) can help:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NODE_MEMBERS \
X(int a, "a")        \
X(char b, "b")

#define X(a, b) a;
struct node {
    NODE_MEMBERS
};
#undef X

#define X(a, b) b,
char *node_member_name[] = {
    NODE_MEMBERS
};
#undef X

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s, %s\n", node_member_name[0], node_member_name[1]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Now I got it, thanks for your time.

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend to create things like this for any purpose. The only reason why you would want to print struct member names is for debug/diagnostic purposes. You shouldn't let such a peripheral thing as system diagnostics determine the whole program design.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible with C. You cannot find all members of a struct you don't know the definition of, and you cannot print the names of variables either without knowing it before.